# What ksav were the tefillin of the GR"A (AKA Vilna Gaon)?

Tags: tefilin, safrus, vilna-gaon

I had always thought the GR''A  wore ksav Beis Yosef but I recently read on https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/the-different-styles-of-script-used-in-stam-today-kesav-beis-yosef-arizal-vallish-source-and-background

> Today’s Arizal script follows the form of letters innovated by
> Rav Nesanel Topilansky, a Jerusalem scribe, who in turn learned it from a
> scribe from Minsk, who in turn learned it from the Parshiyos of the GR”A.

Was the ksav ARI of Rav Nesanel Topilansky actually the ksav that the GR”A used, or is there a source to say otherwise?

Comment: He probably used Lithuanian Ashkenazi Ksav, with perhaps some small variants.

Comment: Based on what source?

Comment: His name "Vilna Gaon"

Comment: That is speculation, which is the mistake I made , and why I asked the question to begin with. Mesorah has no room for speculation.

Comment: Good luck finding his tefillin to prove me wrong. I wouldn't put much stock in that article you referenced which is full of imprecise claims

Comment: I'm not trying to prove you right or wrong. If you are right Yashar Koiach. 

I'm trying to discover what is actually stated in a sefer or heard from someone who can trace it back to someone who actually saw them, or heard it from the GR"A himself.   Being that he was from Vilna doesn't mean anything about his tefillin.

It is known that the GR"A was a Kabbalist in the tradition of the ARI"ZL.

Comment: I don't think you understand how handwriting works. Until the modern era of transportation and photography, everyone wrote more or less like everyone else in town because they all learned from each other. This modern idea that there are specific official scripts is completely anachronistic. Lithuanians wrote like Lithuanians and Germans wrote like Germans and Russians wrote like Russians and Hungarians wrote like Hungarians. Only in the last century did anyone say anything like "I hereby declare this is the one official script for all people from Eastern and Central Europe".

Comment: @DoubleAA Same with Sepharadim. Moroccans and Tunisian scrolls are not written the same as Syrian scrolls. Everything was much more localized than we understand in our modern times

Comment: @Aaron of course, I was just listing Ashkenazi scripts because the OP asked about them